Why are we allowed to create a custom filter including a non-existent tag?
After reading this question, I noticed that it is not possible to create a tag while editing the Watched Tags box or the Ignored Tags box, for example:

which clearly shows that the not-a-tag tag does not exist.
However, it appears to be possible to create a filter including the not-a-tag tag and save this to a custom filter, named for example not-a-tag filter, as follows:

It appears that the /questions/tagged/not-a-tag endpoint thinks that not-a-tag exists as a tag. We can hover over the x next to the tag to display the "Remove tag not-a-tag" tooltip:

We can select another custom filter and then return to the not-a-tag filter and the not-a-tag tag is still there.
When applying a filter with a tag that does not exist, nothing is returned.
Why are we allowed to create a custom filter including a non-existent tag?
